# Toggling state with dynamic key value pair

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have been trying to toggle state using dynamic key value pairs but it doesn't seem to happen.

Here is the state:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    firecrackerAnimation: false,
    mainImageBounceAnimation: false,
    flowersFallingAnimation: false,
  };
}
```

This is the code I am using to toggle state

```
changeAnimation = e => {
   this.setState(
    {
      [e.target.value]: !(this.state[event.target.value]),
    },
    () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    }
);
```

Below is where I am using it inside my render()

```
<div className="form-row">
        <span className="form-label">Animations</span>
        <input
          className=""
          type="checkbox"
          value="firecrackerAnimation"
          onClick={this.changeAnimation}
          checked={this.state.firecrackerAnimation}
        />{" "}
        Fire Cracker Animation <br />
        <input
          className=""
          type="checkbox"
          value="mainImageBounceAnimation"
          onChange={this.changeAnimation}
          checked={this.state.mainImageBounceAnimation}
        />{" "}
        Main Image Bounce <br />
        <input
          className=""
          type="checkbox"
          value="flowersFallingAnimation"
          onChange={this.changeAnimation}
          checked={this.state.flowersFallingAnimation}
        />{" "}
        Flowers Falling Animation <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any error is `console`

Comment: i think you have a typo, it should be `this.state[e.target.value]` not `event.target.value`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `changeAnimation` function as follows:

```
changeAnimation(e){
      var value = e.target.value;
      this.setState({[value]: !(this.state[value])});    
}
```

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/141293/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes I've pointed out:

- You should use `e.target.name` in order to get the name of the `checkbox` being clicked.
- You have to provide `name` for checkboxes, not the `value`

**WORKING DEMO**

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firecrackerAnimation: false,
      mainImageBounceAnimation: false,
      flowersFallingAnimation: false,
    };
  }

  changeAnimation = (e) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        [e.target.name]: !(this.state[e.target.name]),
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-row">
        <span className="form-label">Animations</span>
        <input
          className=""
          type="checkbox"
          name="firecrackerAnimation"
          onChange={this.changeAnimation}
          checked={this.state.firecrackerAnimation}
        />{" "}
        Fire Cracker Animation <br />
        <input
          className=""
          type="checkbox"
          name="mainImageBounceAnimation"
          onChange={this.changeAnimation}
          checked={this.state.mainImageBounceAnimation}
        />{" "}
        Main Image Bounce <br />
        <input
          className=""
          type="checkbox"
          name="flowersFallingAnimation"
          onChange={this.changeAnimation}
          checked={this.state.flowersFallingAnimation}
        />{" "}
        Flowers Falling Animation <br />
      </div>
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 50% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with your change animation event

```js
changeAnimation = e => {
   this.setState(
    {
     // [e.target.value]: !(this.state[event.target.value]),
     //here you have to change like
     this.state[e.target.value]: !(this.state[event.target.value]),
    },
    () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other responses are correct in that you can setState with dynamic keys and variables, however React recommends against using state inside setState.

From the docs:
"React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance. Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state." 
- https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

You can take the same idea as the other comments mention and make setState accept a function instead. I used this in my code (button was defined in an outer function).

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    [button]: !prevState[button]
  }));
```